# Update Trigger from another database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I am trying to update the data from on database to another.  Below is the trigger I wrote but it does not update the Hours column in bEMMR.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_Hours_Trigger]
    on [dbo].[bEMMR]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        Update [dbo].[bEMMR]
            Set bEMMR.Hours = Engine_Hours.rt_CumHours
            from [GPS_Data].[dbo].[Engine_Hours]
            Where bEMMR.Equipment = Engine_Hours.rt_VehicleName
            and bEMMR.EMCo = Engine_Hours.Emco
END;
```

Comment: Is the trigger firing successfully? Are you getting an error? If so can you update your post? You may need to turn on SQL Profiler to monitor/log the operation.

Comment: It is going through successfully.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: SQL Profiler? It's under the Tools menu in SSMS. It's quite verbose if you leave all the options turned on. You will need to include SP:StmtCompleted in the filter options to log the trigger actions. Then once you have the Profiler running, update your table to fire the trigger, then STOP the Profiler and review the log for your statement.

Comment: Your trigger will fire, and update, `bEMMR` when that table is updated, but all of the data you want is coming from elsewhere. (Tip: Since you don't reference the `inserted` or `deleted` tables, something is wrong.) The trigger needs to be on the _source_ data table, i.e. `Engine_Hours`.

Comment: Engine_Hours in the table with all the data and bEMMR is the table I want to put the data into.  Do you code the trigger on the bEMMR table or the Engine Hours table?

Comment: From your question it looks like you are trying to update *all* the records in bEMMR. Is that the case? Or just the record that was updated? I think that is what @HABO is getting at here.

Comment: The trigger is created on the table and statement(s) you want to fire the trigger. If you want an `update` statement on table `Engine_Hours` to fire the trigger then that is what you write: `create trigger Update_Hours_Trigger on Engine_Hours after update as ...`. The trigger typically uses the `inserted` and `deleted` tables, which contain the data changed by the triggering statement, to do what you need. That can be updating a different table, e.g. `bEMMR`.

Comment: I want it to update all the records.  So when the job runs to get the data and input into Engine_Hours I want it to update the bEMMR table.

Comment: Below is a simple update they will update the Hours in bEMMR from Engine Hours.  I just want this to do it automatically                                              update [Viewpoint].[dbo].[bEMMR]
Set bEMMR.Hours = [GPS_Data].[dbo].[Engine_Hours].rt_CumHours
from [Viewpoint].[dbo].[bEMMR]
inner join [GPS_Data].[dbo].[Engine_Hours]
on (bEMMR.Equipment = Engine_Hours.rt_VehicleName)
Where Engine_Hours.rt_VehicleName = '4503';